# What is the console command to join a team in CS 1.6?

Tags: counter-strike

I'm a regular player of some CS 1.6 servers, and to make the joining process easier I'm looking for a console command that allows me to join a team through console, the idea behind that is to automatically join a specified server and start playing directly after launching the game by adding some lines to the `autoexec.cfg` file as follow:

```
connect <server_ip>
the command im looking for to automatically join a team and start playing (it would be something like `join_team ct`)
```

I noticed that by adding these lines to the `autoexec.cfg`:

```
connect <server_ip>
retry
```

the server `retry` during the joining process (before joining the server), so I assume that even if I found the command mentioned above the same thing will happen, so, how to make the second line to be executed only after joining the server?.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is a command to automatically join a team.  You can use the `changeteam` command to pull up the team change menu and then `menuselect 1` to chose T or 2 for CT.

Source:

[CS 1.6 Client And Console Commands](http://cs1-6cfg.blogspot.com/p/cs-16-client-and-console-commands.html)

Answer (score 1):

type in console `jointeam 1 or 2 or 5` 
or just type `jointeam` and the menu will appear